# Using .htaccess to set a cookie and 301 redirect

Tags: htaccess, redirects, 301-redirect, mod-rewrite, cookie

I currently have in my *.htaccess*:

```
RewriteRule ^$ http://chfmaine.com/ [CO=moved:yes:chfmaine.com:1/,R=301,NE,NC,L]
```

I was [basing this off of this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18198757/htaccess-from-www-to-non-www-bringing-variable-in-session-cookie).

That's a lot more than I need but the setting of the cookie should be the same. Maybe I am misunderstanding the domain part of the cookie. If I set it to `CHFmaine.com` shouldn’t that be where it works?

I tried adding the cookie after the 301. Ether way the 301 works but no cookie is passed. This is redirecting from `maine-horse-trails.com` to `chfmaine.com`. I have 23 of these for all the different pages that were on the old site. Anything landing at this `.htaccess` will be redirected and the cookie should be set. So if there is a way to first pass the cookie to anyone then proceed onto the matching rewrite that would be helpful. But if I can get this way to work I dont mind using copy and paste to get it on all the possibilities. and I do not want to pass any queries in the URL.

My question is, what am I doing wrong here? Why can I not find this cookie after a successful redirect? And is there a better option?

Comment: Well, you are setting the cookie while still on `maine-horse-trails.com` so it's not going to be available on `chfmaine.com`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I set a cookie and then redirect in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/612034/how-can-i-set-a-cookie-and-then-redirect-in-php)

Comment: Sorry, I failed to mention that this is set in the .htaccess. not php. I would have to create a large number of directories and other stuff to make the 23 redirects I need due to the way the old site was set up.

Comment: chrome shows this `Set-Cookie: moved=yes; path=/; domain=.chfmaine.com; expires=Thu, 12-Dec-2013 03:51:41 GMT` But that cookie is not set at all

Answer (score 3):

You can't find the cookie after a redirect because the cookie is never set. The redierect happens in Apache, before any PHP or other code is run.

You could use a PHP redirect. For example, land on the page, set the cookie, then redirect.

See this question for more information. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/612034/how-can-i-set-a-cookie-and-then-redirect-in-php

Also, cookies are domain specific. If you set a cookie on one site, it doesn't carry over to the next. Depending on what you're using the cookie for, a $_GET may be a better option.

Comment: $_GET would work but for SEO it will mess things up. All it is doing is displaying a message to the user reminding them to update links. and PHP redirects would be a lot of work to generate and maintain. there are 23 all in the form of /somepath/someother/. I would have to create 46 directories plus the 23 redirects.

Comment: In that case, you could likely make one PHP file that reads the $SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] and acts accordingly. Use .htaccess to forward all relevant requests to that file. 

Why do you need to set the cookie?

Comment: A cookie seems to be the only way I can pass a variable when a user is redirected. It just triggers a script that changes the notification div from display none to block

Comment: A cookie by design won't work since it's a different domain. You'll have to use either a GET or a POST. If you don't want it to appear in the url, use POST. Either way, you'll likely have to use PHP or another scripting language.

Comment: The first 3 paragraphs are irrelevant - the actual answer is in the last paragraph: "cookies are domain specific". What you are trying to do is set a cookie on one website from another - cross domain browser security - the browser won't allow this.